# Trouble having Heroku recognize gitignored api keys in react app

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, heroku, gitignore

I am having problems getting Heroku to recognize my api keys that I have gitignored on my React app.

I have created credentials.js with my api keys and exported it.

```
export const API_KEY = 'redacted';
```

Then I listed credentials.js in gitignore.

```
credentials.js
```

I then imported API_KEY into my project file.

```
import { API_KEY } from '../credentials.js';
```

This works fine in development but when I push to Heroku, it fails to resolve the path to credentials and the compile fails since it's in a gitignored file. I have also tried using a .env file, but that does not work either.

I have tried not importing it and just running the Heroku "config set" command in the terminal, but to no avail.

```
$heroku config:set API_KEY=<key>
```

Also the issue is importing the API_KEY gitignored variable in the index.html file. How do you do this in a React app like you can do with application.yml file in rails and referencing it with #{ENV[API_KEY]}?

Does anyone have a tried and tested solution?

Comment: Your `credentials.js` file does not exist when you're pushing on Heroku because `Then I listed credentials.js in gitignore`.

Comment: Yes, I realize. I do it for github pushes as well. However, how does one referrence the api keys in the code in React so that Heroku will pick it up as an environmental variable like #{ENV['API_KEY']} in the rails environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already set the API_KEY on Heroku env using the command you mentioned, in order to use it you need to do something like:

```
const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY;
```

This way you'll be able to read from Heroku env. You can see more info [here](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env).

Comment: Thanks. That looks promising. Where would you run const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY. And how can I also reference it on index.html. In other words, how can you interpolated this variable in HTML code in React?

Comment: Instead of exporting it, you use it as a variable. The interpolation would be done as any other variable

Comment: I tried dotenv and that did not work on my app. I may be able to work through the errors, but do you recommend any other tools other than to input the environmental variables in the command line?

Comment: For some reason I had to specify process.env.google_api_key on heroku instead of just google_api_key = some key... I'm using webpack-dotenv. Perhaps it's not working right but it's working.